# How to play one audio file at a time with drag drop javascript html5

Tags: javascript, html, audio

im trying to figure out how to play one audio file at once. I have multiple audio attributes that I will dynamically create via javascript and html5. For instance I will drag and drop a audio file on one div and it will play, but I want to able to drag and drop another audio file on another div and stop the audio file so one audio attribute is playing. A snippet of my code is below, I can provide a JSFiddle if needed also thanks!!

```
      <div id="target_container">
        <div  id="drop_target0" class="audio_box">Drop Media Files Here</div>
        <div  id="drop_target1" class="audio_box">Drop Media Files Here</div>
       </div>


             function handleEvent(event){

                switch(event.type){
                case "drop":
                case "dragdrop":

                    if(this.id === "drop_target0"){
                        divTarget("drop_target0","File Drop Successfully");

                       var song0 = document.createElement("audio");
                       song0.setAttribute('src',document.getElementById("drop_target0").src= event.dataTransfer.getData('url') );
                       song0.autoplay = true;


                    if(this.id === "drop_target1"){
                        divTarget("drop_target1","File Drop Successfully");


                        var song = document.createElement("audio");
                        song.setAttribute('src',document.getElementById("drop_target1").src= event.dataTransfer.getData('url') );
                        song.autoplay = true;

                    }
                   // Checks to see if div 0 is playing 

                   if(!document.getElementById("drop_target0).paused){
                        alert("Cant play multiple files at once");
                        document.getElementById("drop_target1).pause()
                    }
                  // Checks to see if div 1 is playing

                   if(!document.getElementById("drop_target1).paused){
                        alert("Cant play multiple files at once");
                        document.getElementById("drop_target0).pause()
                    }

                  }
            }
       EventUtil.addHandler(document.getElementById("drop_target0"),"drop", handleEvent);
       EventUtil.addHandler(document.getElementById("drop_target1"),"dragdrop", handleEvent);
```

Comment: do not set autoplay to true if another is running.

Comment: @epascarello, But i want the audio to autoplay when I drag and drop the file on the element

Comment: Wait; you want the second one to start to play and the first one to stop? I think I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: @ epascarello, yes, for all the elements that im going to create, not just these two.. for instance if i drag and drop an audio file to the id of drop_target2 while the id of drop_target3 is playing I want to stop drop_target3 etc...

Comment: So keep track of the file that is playing and pause it?

Comment: @epascarello, Got it!!.. thanks for the quick assistance,  I forgot I could declare a global variable and keep track of the file being played with it, then be able to pause it.. :)